# Builder pattern with setup correctness guaranteed at compile time

Tags: go, generics, builder

I have created a module to make HTTP requests that it's used like:

```golang
response, err := Get[ResponseType]("https://example.com").
  Query("foo", "bar").
  Header("Accept", "text/plain").
  Do(context.Background())
```

It uses a builder together with generics to simplify making HTTP requests.

While (IMO) the builder pattern reads well, I'm now trying to enforce some checks at compile time. For instance, an `http.Client` is needed to make the actual HTTP calls. I want to let users inject their own `http.Client` or instruct the builder to use a default one. Like this:

```golang
response, err := Get[ResponseType]("https://example.com").
  Client(myHttpClient).
  Do(context.Background())

// or

response, err := Get[ResponseType]("https://example.com").
  UseDefaultClient().
  Do(context.Background())
```

If none of these two ways to specify the client is used, then I'd like the builder to fail at compile time. I've tried to do this using generics, but I haven't managed to get a fully satisfying solution. This is what I've got so far:

```golang
// R is for response type, C is for config state

type Builder[R any, C any] struct {
    httpClient *http.Client
}

type NoClient struct{}

type WithClient struct{}

func Get[R any](requestUrl string) *Builder[R, NoClient] {
    return &Builder[R, NoClient]{ /* ... */ }
}

func (b *Builder[R, C]) Client(httpClient *http.Client) *Builder[R, WithClient] {
    b.httpClient = httpClient
    return (*Builder[R, WithClient])(b)
}

func (b *Builder[R, C]) UseDefaultClient() *Builder[R, WithClient] {
    b.httpClient = &http.Client{}
    return (*Builder[R, WithClient])(b)
}

func (b *Builder[R, C]) Header(key string, value string) *Builder[R, C] {
    /* add header */
    return b
}

func (b *Builder[R, C]) Do(ctx context.Context) (Response[R], error) {
    /* execute request */
}
```

I would like calls to method `Do` to fail at compile time if the type is `Builder[R, NoClient]`, and succeed otherwise. But, I believe this is not possible. The compiler is completely fine with:

```golang
response, err := Get[ResponseType]("https://example.com").
    Do(context.Background())
```

as there is no constraint on the receiver pointer for method `Do` (and AFAIK it's not possible to add one).

One potential solution I have found is to use function instead of a method:

```golang
func ExecuteRequest[R any](
    ctx context.Context,
    builder *Builder[R, WithClient],
) (Response[R], error) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Now this fails at compile time, as desired:

```golang
response, err := ExecuteRequest(
    context.Background(),
    Get[ResponseType]("https://example.com")
)
```

I was wondering if it's actually possible to solve this while keeping the `Get[R](...).Do()` approach. And while I used a concrete example to (hopefully) make it easier to understand the problem, I think enforcing compile-time guarantees for builders can be useful in many situations.

Answer (score 0):

So, you basically want to force the users of your builder to specifically set the client before making any requests. Then just limit their interface with something that only has these two methods.

One way of achieving the goal is to use the intermediate builder that only allows to set the client, here is an example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type Response[T any] struct{}

type ClientBuilder[R any] struct {
    base *Builder[R]
}

func (b *ClientBuilder[R]) WithClient(httpClient *http.Client) *Builder[R] {
    b.base.httpClient = httpClient
    return b.base
}

func (b *ClientBuilder[R]) DefaultClient() *Builder[R] {
    b.base.httpClient = &http.Client{}
    return b.base
}

type Builder[R any] struct {
    httpClient *http.Client
}

func Get[R any](requestUrl string) *ClientBuilder[R] {
    return &ClientBuilder[R]{&Builder[R]{}}
}

func (b *Builder[R]) Header(key string, value string) *Builder[R] {
    /* add header */
    return b
}

func (b *Builder[R]) Do(ctx context.Context) (Response[R], error) {
    fmt.Println(b.httpClient == http.DefaultClient)
    /* execute request */
    return Response[R]{}, nil
}

func main() {
    // This will fail on compile
    response, err := Get[string]("https://example.com").
        Do(context.Background())

    // This wont
    response, err := Get[string]("https://example.com").
        DefaultClient().
        Do(context.Background())

    fmt.Println(response, err)
}
```

But I think having default client setting requirement is a bit too verbose, following your initial code sample I would just remove the `UseDefaultClient` completely and just use one in Do method when the user decided to not set a custom one:

```golang
func (b *Builder[R, C]) Do(ctx context.Context) (Response[R], error) {
    client := b.httpClient
    if client == nil {
        client = &http.Client{}
    }
    /* execute request */
}
```